# Vector shape and Dimensions

Tags: assignment, vector-calculus

I think I have not understood clearly the difference between dimension and shape. I want to construct a vector remembering recurrence of the type :

```
({{f[0]},{g[0]}}) = ({{1},{1}})

{{f[n_]},{g[n_]}}) := ({{f[n]},{g[n]}}) = ({{0.2 f[n - 1] +  g[n - 1] + 1}, { f[n - 1] + 0.2 g[n - 1] + 1}} )
```

gives the following error

> SetDelayed::shape: Lists {{f[n]},{g[n]}} and {{f[n]},{g[n]}}={{0.2
>   f[n-1]+g[n-1]+1},{f[n-1]+0.2 g[n-1]+1}} are not the same shape.

but according to `Dimensions` they are both equal to

> {2, 1}

So what is the difference between shape and dimensions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use something like:

```
{a, b} := {1, 2}
```

This gets interpreted as:

```
a := 1; b := 2
```

as long as both sides are lists of the same length. If they are not, then it doesn't work:

```
{a, b} := Range[2]
```

> SetDelayed::shape: Lists {a,b} and Range[2] are not the same shape.
>
> $Failed

Now consider your example:

```
Hold[{{f[n], g[n]}} := {{f[n], g[n]}} = rhs] //FullForm
```

> Hold[SetDelayed[List[List[f[n],g[n]]],Set[List[List[f[n],g[n]]],rhs]]]

Note that the RHS of SetDelayed is a an object with head Set, not a nested list. This is why it doesn't work. You could try the following instead:

```
Clear[f,g]

{{f[0]}, {g[0]}} = {{1},{1}};

f[n_] := (
    {{f[n]}, {g[n]}} = {{f[n]},{g[n]}}={{0.2 f[n-1]+g[n-1]+1},{f[n-1]+0.2 g[n-1]+1}}
)[[1, 1]]

g[n_] := (
    {{f[n]}, {g[n]}} = {{f[n]},{g[n]}}={{0.2 f[n-1]+g[n-1]+1},{f[n-1]+0.2 g[n-1]+1}}
)[[1, 2]]
```

Then:

```
f[3]
```

> 5.368

and let's check that definitions for both `f` and `g` have been cached:

```
Definition[f]
```

> ```
> f[0]=1
> f[1]=2.2
> f[2]=3.64
> f[3]=5.368
> f[n_]:=({{f[n]},{g[n]}}={{f[n]},{g[n]}}={{0.2 f[n-1]+g[n-1]+1},{f[n-1]+0.2 g[n-1]+1}})[[1,1]]
> ```

and:

```
Definition[f]
```

> ```
> g[0]=1
> g[1]=2.2
> g[2]=3.64
> g[3]=5.368
> g[n_]:=({{f[n]},{g[n]}}={{f[n]},{g[n]}}={{0.2 f[n-1]+g[n-1]+1},{f[n-1]+0.2 g[n-1]+1}})[[1,2]]
> ```